# Using basic jQuery append function, how would you put user-submitted text into it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
function createPost(){
    $('#body').append("<p>Welcome to calmspace.</p>");
}
```

How would I utilize user input so the user can create a post with their own message? I am a newbie with jQuery so if this is a stupid question please forgive me. Possible duplicate but I couldn't find another post like this.

Comment: can u please plus one if my response answers ur question or comment if thats not what ur looking for ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am not exactly sure what you want to do from your question. In future questions you will find it helpful to provide more detail on exactly what you want to do with your application or function.

The basic idea here is to use a button or any action you can capture with jQuery (like pressing `enter` or checking `$(element).on('click',...` and then putting that info where you want using `$(element).html(...)` or `.append(...)`.

Here is a fiddle I made with the rough idea. Try to use this fiddle tool a lot, and you can also post the link to what you have tried in future questions. Good luck :-)

[JSFiddle example of submitting a post](https://jsfiddle.net/roe7mqwv/11/)

Comment: I see another user said not to use '#body', but that is okay if you have a div with an ID of 'body', of course.

Answer (score 0):

First things first - you should not have added '#' in front of body, it'd mean that the body element is of id 'body', assigning id to an element that is unique does not bear that much sense, instead you should just target the tag - $('body').

In order to provide some sort of message you first have to capture it, for instance using some sort of input. Here is a working [demo](https://jsbin.com/doyonitema/edit?html,js,console,output).

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
    createPost($('#text').val());
})
```

You read it as follows, grab element of id 'submit', assign it a click event, grab the value of input box of id 'text' and pass it to a function named create post which accepts a string parameter and then prints it in a `<p>` tag.

Comment: Thanks, i used #body because i have a div with the id of body.

Comment: Simion: I think you will find my answer below more helpful, and if you please mark it correct if so :).

Answer (score 0):

@Simion Benderschii a working example of a [post](https://jsbin.com/ceqagacuwe/25/edit?html,output) which appends to the document or sends via ajax. Hope this helps

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <h2>Enter your post here</h2>
    <form>
      <textarea id='user-input-post'></textarea>
      <div>
        <button id=user-post-button>Post</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>Below are your posts</h2>
    <ul id='user-post-display'>
      
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
  <script>
    /*possible options can be
      'display' - which shows the post in the UI in a unordered list
      'ajax' - which send the post to the server via ajax
    */
    var post_type = 'display';
    //the id of the list where the post will be appended
    var list_id = '#user-post-display';
    //the id where the post will be entered
    var post_id = '#user-input-post';
    //the id of the button which triggers some action
    var button_id = '#user-post-button';
    
    //this gets the post from the textarea
    var get_post = function() {
      var post = $(post_id).val();
      return encodeURIComponent(post);
    };
    
    //this appends the post to the list
    var append_post = function() {
      var post = get_post();
      var html_string = '';
      if (post) {
         html_string = '<li>' + post + '</li>';
        $(list_id).append(html_string);
      }
    };
    
    //this sends the post via ajax and triggers callbacks
    var send_post = function() {
      var post = get_post();
      var post_created_on = Date.now();
      var url = 'dummy_url_for_posting';
      $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: { data: {
          post: post,
          post_created_on: post_created_on
        }}
      })
        .done(function() {
          window.alert('post success');
        })
        .fail(function() {
          window.alert('post fail');
        })
        .always(function() {
          window.alert('post triggered');
        });
    }
    
    //main function which is the entry point
    var main = function() {
      $(button_id).on('click', function() {
        event.preventDefault();
        debugger;
        if (post_type === 'display') {
          append_post();
        } else if (post_type === 'ajax') {
          send_post();
        }
      });
    };
    
    //triggers the main function
    main();
    
  </script>
</html>
```